PySide6 QtDesigner can't edit proprieties
I tried lunch QtDesigner via terminal.
Upon startup after creating a new project, when I try to change properties of a window, such as its size, the software doesn't let me change the number anymore.
I don't understand what went wrong or how this error was created.
I tried uninstalling PySide6 and all related libraries. I deleted all the QtDesigner folders in AppLocal and then restarted the PC. Then i did a clean install of PySide6.
However when starting QtDesigner this problem persists. I attach a video to better understand the issue.
I have no idea how to fix this problem.
Video Here
Im on Windows EnvirormetnIm on Windows Environment using Python 3.10

More importantly than the Python version, you should report the Qt version, since Designer has nothing to do with Python. But considering the recent amount of similar posts, I'm assuming you're using 6.7.1, and it's a known bug. Downgrade to 6.7.0 until 6.7.2 is released (unless you want to build it on your own).

Make sure PySide6 and Qt Designer are properly installed. You can reinstall PySide6 and verify the installation by running:
pip install --upgrade PySide6

